# javascript: form cannot submit after finishing countdown

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

i make a countdown in my mcq web page 
when the countdown finish i need to automatically submit my form with javascript
but it doesn't work 
**my javascript code is below **

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/AdvancedCountDown.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=WindowLoad;
function WindowLoad(event) {

ActivateCountDown("CountDownPanel1",10, "CountDownEnded1");

}
function CountDownEnded1()
{
var answer = confirm("Your time is expired!\n if you want to get result click 'ok'");

if(answer==true)
{

   document.forms["myform"].submit()

}
else
{
 document.forms["myform"].submit()
}


}
</script>
```

and my html form code is

```
 form id="myform" action="result" method="post"
```

after countdown finish its not working and form cannot submited

so can anybody help me..??

Comment: This => `action="result"` doesn't sound right ot me. It's usually a file name or left empty.

Comment: @Fred -ii- it's a file name like "<? echo base_url()."/index.php/QuizController/result";?>" but it's not go to the link

Comment: Then try `<? echo base_url()."/index.php/QuizController/result/index.php";?>` if `result` is a folder

Comment: @Fres -ii- its not the exact problem the problem is javascript submit is not working after countdown finished . but when i manually press submit button its works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.forms['myform'].submit();
    }, 10000); // milliseconds here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a string, not referencing the function?

It's hard to tell how this works without the `ActivateCountDown` function, but assuming a regular callback you'd do :

```
ActivateCountDown("CountDownPanel1", 10, CountDownEnded1);
```

Also, you're submitting the form no matter what the user answers in the confirm ?

Comment: after finishing the countdown a alert come and two option ok and cancel . when ok then the form submitted . but its not submitted the form @adeneo

Comment: @nadimsajib - Not sure I get it, but the if / else does the same thing in both conditions, so the form should be submitted no matter what the user answers ?

Comment: user answer is ok @adeneo